# Temporarily block prints to System.out in Java

Tags: java, logging, stdout

Say I have some method or operation `ReturnType method(ArgType argument)` in Java. I want to make it so that invoking `method` will not cause some message to be written to System.out, and afterwards the behaviour should be as before. My naive idea for something doing this would be to write the following code:

```
PrintStream systemout = System.out
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream()))
method(arg)
System.setOut(systemout)
```

But it does not seem to work. Is there some straightforward way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Is this kinda what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172384/recreate-system-out-to-print-again-in-console-after-system-out-close

Comment: If you're still seeing output after redirecting `System.out`, considering redirecting `System.err` too.

Comment: Bless you, @Kayaman! System.err was indeed the "sinner"!